# How to force re-render if map value changes?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code

relevent part of the parent:

```
  const [aggregated] = React.useState(new Map());
  let updateAggregate = (month:string, value:number) => {
    let init = aggregated.get(month) || 0;
    aggregated.set(month, init + value);
  };
  return (
    <AggregateRow classes={classes} resource={resource} aggregated={aggregated} test={changed}/>
  )
```

Child:

```
export interface AggregateRowProps {
  classes: Record<"tableCell", string>,
  resource: Resource,
  aggregated: Map<string, number>,
  test: boolean
}
export const AggregateRow = (props: AggregateRowProps) => {
  console.log("map", props.aggregated);
  return (
    <TableRow hover className={props.classes.tableCell}>
      {months.map((item, i) => <TableCell key={i}>{props.aggregated.get(item) || 0}</TableCell>)}
    </TableRow>
  )
};
```

I want to rerender this `TableRow` when the map (`props.aggregated`) is updated, I see in the `console.log` that `props.aggregated` is updating correctly, however the `TableRow` is always full of 0s from the initial render.

Is this because the props.aggregated isn't seen as changed since it is still the same map (with different values inside)?

Comment: When you update `props.aggregated`, are you assigning a new value to `props.aggregated` (i.e. creating a new `Map`), or just appending values to the current object?

Comment: appending values with `aggregated.set(key, value)`, which is probably the problem.

Comment: Can we see the parent component as well? It has to do with the way you updated the props

Comment: The component will re-render when its props change, but as `props.aggregated` is the same object, this doesn't happen.

Comment: added parent, the `updateAggregate` function is getting called by the other components. The map value works since I see the map values in console.log(aggregate) but the table only shows 0 from the initial render.

Comment: @JMadelaine I guess I can set the map every time to a new map, but doesn't seem very efficient at all, anyway to force a re-render? because the console.log(aggregate) line happens 3 times so can I somehow force an rerender each of those times?

Comment: Instead of using a `Map` you could store your data as an object: `{ [key: string]: number }`. Then instead of calling `aggregated.set(key, value)` you can just create a new object: `{ ...aggregated, ...{ key: val } }`. This would be a new object reference so your component would re-render.

Comment: I've summarized my comments in an answer and provided an example using a keyed object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update `props.aggregated`, you are appending values to the current object rather than assigning a new value to `props.aggregated` (i.e. creating a new `Map`).

The component will re-render when its props change, but as `props.aggregated` is the same object, this doesn't happen.

You could recreate the `Map` each time instead of appending to it, or you could store your key-value pairs in a simple `object` with the following type:

```
{ [key: string]: number }
```

Then instead of calling `aggregated.set(key, value)` you can just create a new object and append the new key-value pair to it:

```
{
  ...oldObject,
  ...{ newKey: (oldObject[newKey] || 0) + newValue },
}
```

I wouldn't worry about how efficient this is, as React was designed to be used in this way. State is immutable, so creating new state (rather than mutating old state) is the way to go.

This would be a new object reference so your component would re-render when new key-value pairs are added to your state.

Here's an example:

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [aggregated, setAggregated] = useState<{ [key: string]: number }>({})

    let updateAggregate = (month: string, value: number) => {
        // We set aggregated as a new object, with the new month and value added as a property.
        setAggregated(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            ...{ month: (prev[month] || 0) + value },
        }))
    }
    return <AggregateRow classes={classes} resource={resource} aggregated={aggregated} test={changed}/>
}

export const AggregateRow = (props: AggregateRowProps) => {
  return (
    <TableRow hover className={props.classes.tableCell}>
      // Access the correct prop using props.aggregated[item]
      {months.map((item, i) => <TableCell key={i}>{props.aggregated[item] || 0}</TableCell>)}
    </TableRow>
  )
};
```